# WickedPdf CSS rule `page-break-after: avoid` does not work as expected

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, printing, wicked-pdf

I want the page to not break between two divs. When I assign the CSS rule **page-break-after: avoid** or **page-break-before: avoid**, it simply does not work, but if I assign set **page-break-before: always**, it works perfectly, can anyone help me?

Here is the code and result:

[image: The html code with page break props]

[image: page breaking between divs]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `page-break-inside: avoid;`, not before or after.

That rule should be applied to a wrapping container that you want to avoid page breaks inside, however it is ultimately up to the browser to decide. If you want to help make sure there is enough room, it can be helpful to also apply `page-break-before: always;`, to ensure the element you don't want to break starts at the top and has a lot of space.

Comment: I have the same problem as this one and tried to fix the problem using your suggestion. When I tested by printing the html page (using Ctrl-p on browser), it can successfully give the page break in the right place. However, the pdf file from wicked_pdf doesn't give me the page break. I also tried putting 'print_media_type: true', but still have no luck.